# MVC5 routing to 404

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a legacy WebForms website to which I am attempting to add new MVC 5 pages.

I am running VS Express 2013 / IISExpress

I have followed instructions from these pages:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38778/ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Harmony
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view

I ran the "Manage NuGet Packages" on my project and installed ASP.NET MVC and all dependancies.

I added references to System.Web.Routing, System.Web.Mvc, and System.Web.Razor, created a basic View and Controller.

Everything builds and runs.

I can set breakpoints and see that my routes are being created as follows when the application starts:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "AdminPages",
            "Admin/{controller}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard" }
            );
    }
```

I tried adding attribute routing as described here:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4PK4010514-Understanding-Attribute-Routing-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

controller:

```
 namespace ConnectBusiness.Controllers
 {
     [RoutePrefix("Admin")]
     [Route("{action=index}")]
     public class DashboardController : Controller
     {

         // Dashboard/Index
         public ActionResult Index()
         {
             return View();
             //return View("~/MVC5/Views/Administration/Dashboard.cshtml");
         }
     }
 }
```

Web.config has the following Handlers entires:

```
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

But when I try to navigate to what I think is the correct URL, I always get redirected to default.aspx which results in a 404:

`http: //localhost:57330/Admin/Dashboard --> http: //localhost:57330/Admin/Dashboard/default.aspx --> 404`

Any ideas what is causing the 404 redirect and how I can successfully navigate to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by UrlRewritingNet (http://www.urlrewriting.net) being installed in the config.

Lesson learned: remove other Url rewriters and let MVC handle the url rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have an index view in Views/Dashboard/index.cshtml ? That's the file that it will be looking for if you hit the Index action.
2. Have you enabled the attribute routing? Make sure to enable it before the convention-based routing, so that it will match the attribute routing first.

   ```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //enabling attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //convention-based routing
        /routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
   ```

If you want the URL do be *localhost:57330/Admin/Dashboard* try this:

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin")]
[Route("{action=index}")]  //default action
public class DashboardController : Controller
{

   // route: /Admin/Dashboard
   [Route("Dashboard")]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

The way you have it set up I think the URL would be *localhost:57330/Admin* or *localhost:57330/Admin/Index*